# Fixed margin and VW (viewport width) units conflict

Tags: html, css

I have a container which has 40px of padding. Inside of that container I have an image and text.

I am trying to keep the image and the text in sync. If I resize the window, my image gets resized automatically, and I am trying to use units "vw" to keep my text in sync with the image, but it's not working as I would like to. The padding is conflicting somehow, but I am not sure what the correct solution would be.

Here is my simple example:

```css
.main {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  font-size: 6.8vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 12%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">

    <img src="http://screenshots.chriseelmaa.com/temp/d_slider_1_1_jpg__1918×880__1F40F570.png" />

    <span class="text">YOUR SHAPE.</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zn4odjrc/

As you can see, if you drag the browser window very small, and very big, the text is moving out of sync from the image. How should I handle the fixed margin in the calculations?

I've tried crazy stuff like `font-size: calc(3vw - 40px)`, but no luck.

//edit:

with the help of Nils, I managed to pin down line-height & font-size and get this result:

https://jsfiddle.net/zn4odjrc/6/

I am almost satisfied with the result, however I don't understand why the first letter is not anchored, it moves quite a lot when you minimise browser really small / big.

As you can see, the top & line height seems to be fixed correctly. I don't care about letter-spacing right now, however it's not fixed on horizontal axis, I suspect it's because of left: 20%, which should be more a long of the lines of left: calc(20px + (100% - 40px) * 0.3)

Comment: Why you dont use text-shadow?

Comment: @Duannx I am not trying to create a shadow, rather, I am converting an existing image to HTML which should resize itself exactly like image.

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa Text's `font-family` is different than image's `font-family`, in order to sync/match them properly you have to use same font, because different fonts have their different kernings it's not possible to sync/match each and every characters.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey I understand that, however I think no matter the fonts & sizes, the leftmost point location should stay the same. I think Nils answer is very close, however it's not 100% fixed (the left-top point)

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa see comment from Aug 21 at 9:58

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to express the font-size not only by viewport width but also the padding. So the correct calculation would be something like: `font-size: calc((100vw - 40px) * 0.072);`.

Explanation: Your desired font size is relative to the width of the image, which can be expressed as `fontSize = imageWidth * factor`. The image width is defined as 100% of the container, but the container is 100% of the viewport minus 40px

Comment: makes sense - I've updated the post. It's almost what I want however I don't understand why the first letter is moving so much when you minimise the browser window to small / big. I suspect that it is due to the "left: 20%", which doesn't account for the fact that there is fixed margin as well.

Comment: It's the same issue. The percentage value is based on the container and not the image. They are not linear related. So while keeping your markup you would need to do something like `left: calc(20px + ((100vw - 40px) * 0.175));`.

Answer (score 11):

It's hard to sync pixels with percentage (static with  dynamic). every unit should be dynamic.

```css
.main {
  padding-left: 1vw;
  padding-right: 1vw;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  font-size: 7.3vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 18.2%;
  top: 11%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">

    <img src="http://screenshots.chriseelmaa.com/temp/d_slider_1_1_jpg__1918×880__1F40F570.png" />

    <span class="text">YOUR SHAPE.</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zn4odjrc/4/)** with unknown font

---

**Edit**

I cannot find the font used in image provided by you, so I changed image's first para with *Times new roman*.

Now you can see it's bit easy to trace image with correct font family, although you need to manually trace the starting point of text.

```css
.main {
  padding-left: 1vw;
  padding-right: 1vw;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  font-size: 7.3vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 18.2%;
  top: 11%;
  font-family:
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktEew.png" />
    <span class="text">YOUR SHAPE.</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zn4odjrc/9/)** with *Times new roman* font used in image

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `6.8vw`, use `6.8vmin`.

https://jsfiddle.net/zn4odjrc/2/

Comment: doesnt seem to work: it doesn't scale uniformly with the image

Comment: I just realised that it might be due to the different types of fonts used in the image and the text. The spacing between the individual letters seems to differ. I think that might be the issue.

Comment: it doesn't matter to me as much that the letters don't match, as the fonts are different in JSFiddle, but more of, why doesn't my font-size scale linearly like it should? If I do width: calc(100vw - 40px) on a div with height:1, it scales linearily.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to make the shadow of text in the image. You can do it with CSS. Edit your image and remove the shadow then apply this CSS to your text:

see this

> https://codepen.io/prateek89760/pen/PKRKeQ

```
.main {
  padding-left: 1vw;
  padding-right: 1vw;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
text-shadow: 6px 6px #ccc;
  font-size: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 18.2%;
  top: 11%;
}
```

```
<img src="" />

<span class="text">YOUR SHAPE.</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using .text{ /* css code */ }, use

```
<style type="text/css">
.text {
  left: 0;
  font-size: 6.8vw;
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  top: 12%;
  width: 100%
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

The edited version runs nearly fine but all values are relative excepting the `padding`. Thats the reason why the positions are changing on small or large resolutions.

Change padding to this:

```
.main  {
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zn4odjrc/8/

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer, i don't know if this exactly what you want but maybe can give an insight.
I change the .main to position to absolute so that your text will resize base on main div

```css
.main  {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  display: block;
  font-size: calc((100vw - 40px) * 0.072);
  line-height: calc((100vw - 40px) * 0.082);
  margin-left: 18%;
  margin-top: -17%;
  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">

    <img
    src="http://screenshots.chriseelmaa.com/temp/d_slider_1_1_jpg__1918×880__1F40F570.png"/>

    <span class="text">YOUR SHAPE.</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @erti-chris-eelmaa i try to resize the window both the width and height and it works like the sample u provide too..hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Quick Solution:
    its all about the starting point and right font.

Explanation:
 after a long review of the code i can say that the solution given by @Abhishek Pandey is a good solution. the thing is though, you need to find to correct begining point of the text and use the exact same font with font-family being correct and font-weight being correct. check it because they dont seem to fit.